# Is it a good practice for various AWS EC2 instances use the same library files in a AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm migrating my computations to aws.
I plan to have e.g: 10 aws EC2 instances but they need to use e.g.: 1000 library files (each like 5MB-10 MB) in total circa 10GB of library files.

Shall I upload these 10GB of library files to each instance? Will it be more costly and faster?

Or, first create a S3 bucket, only upload 10GB of files to S3 bucket and then make the instances make use library files in S3 Bucket?

Or is it possible to upload library files to an EC2 instance (library instance) and make other EC2 instances to make use this library instance?

This can  be a very stupid question.
But since I'm in the very first days of aws, I need your good ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few ways you could approach this.

1. Your idea of uploading each file to each instance would work just fine. To speed up the process, you could copy all the files to one instance (slow), and copy from there to each of the other instances (faster).
2. Your idea to copy the files to S3, then load the files from S3 on each instance is a more typical approach. More efficient from a transfer standpoint since you'd only need to copy the files once to S3, then load in to each instance.
3. Use [Amazon Elastic File System (EFS)](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/). Mount the volume on each of your instances. Copy the data on to the volume, then it will be accessible on all of them. Pros: No need to operate on the files in S3, available on all instances regardless of which availability zone they are in. Cons: more complex to set up.
4. Attach an EBS volume to each instance using the [recently launched multi-attach support](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-multi-attach-for-provisioned-iops-io1-amazon-ebs-volumes/). Pros: Easy to set configure, fastest option. Cons: All the instances must be located in the same availability zone.

Hey, at least you have some options!

Comment: For the 4th option: Will there be only one EBS volume? What is the cost of EBS? And one EBS can be attached to various EC2 instances?

Comment: You'd need just one EBS volume with Provisioned IOPS. See the pricing page [here](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/). You'd have 10GB data and to save on cost you could choose the lowest possible PIOPS which I think is 100. This would be around $5/mo.

Comment: Can the EC2 instance reach the file given as full path to the file in EBS?  By the way I could not find EBS but EFS in aws services.

Comment: EBS is a service within EC2. [Here is a link to more docs than you ever needed on EBS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AmazonEBS.html). But don't be intimidated by the docs - EBS is really easy to use.

Comment: The EBS volume is mounted as a local filesystem on an instance. You can access files on the volume just like you would any other local file.

Comment: Here https://aws.amazon.com/tr/ebs/getting-started/?nc=nsb&pg=pr It is written that "A volume can only be attached to one instance at a time, but many volumes can be attached to a single instance. " So one volume will not be able to serve to multiple EC2 instances at the same time. Maybe I should try option1 thenl. Thanks.

Comment: No, I believe that statement is out-of-date. The multi-attach feature is new and they probably need to update this statement.

Comment: Note that it must be a Provisioned IOPS EBS volume (type `io1`) for the multi-attach to work. See the blog post I mentioned above.

Comment: Yes, you wrote this multi-attach feature of EBS before. By the way when we launch a EC2 instance, for storage there is EBS and SSD options. When we select EBS, is it the same EBS you have written in Option4?

Comment: That's probably referring to the root volume type of the instance. If you choose EBS, your volume will be persistent; that is, you can stop and start it. Perhaps [this article](https://help.acloud.guru/hc/en-us/articles/115003534253-AWS-EC2-Instance-Store-vs-EBS) will help you to understand it.

Comment: It is the same EBS, ultimately, but in addition to the root volume you can attach more volumes, including a PIOPS volume with multi-attach.

Comment: My question becomes for reading data from disk (library files) and writing results (computations using input files and library files) to disk, must I select an EC2 instance with an EBS storage or SSD storage to speed up computations?

Comment: You can choose either one, however, I usually choose EBS and I recommend that for you in this case.

Comment: My mind is going between options. Is there a volume that can be attached to multiple EC2 instances and each instance can read the same file from that volume like a local file level access? Does EBS provide this and is EBS  slower than keeping the library files local in the EC2 instance? Also here https://aws.amazon.com/tr/blogs/aws/new-multi-attach-for-provisioned-iops-io1-amazon-ebs-volumes/  It writes that "Enabling multiple servers to simultaneously access a standard file system can result in data corruption or loss". What kind of file system do I have in EBS and EC2 instances?

Comment: > Is there a volume that can be attached to multiple EC2 instances and each instance can read the same file from that volume like a local file level access
This is basically what the multi-attach EBS option is. You format the volume once, then mount it from multiple instances simultaneously. Then it is available for read/write from all the instances that you've mounted it on.

Comment: > Enabling multiple servers to simultaneously access a standard file system can result in data corruption or loss
This can happen if you're not careful with how the data is handled. For example, imagine that Node A and Node B both have the volume mounted and are accessing the same files. If node A modifies a file in a particular way, and node B tries to modify the same file at the same time, this might leave the file in a corrupt state.

Comment: If you don't need to write any data, which it sounds like in your case, then you could even mount the filesystem as read only, and you'd avoid any corruption issues.

Comment: Thanks @Ben Whaley My question: Will reading libray files from EBS be slower than reading from EC2 instance itself? Assume that files are on EBS, library files will be read-only, but input files will be under different input directories for each job. And each job will write  some extra files under their specific input directories. Therefore filesystem can not be read only, however since they do not write on the same file, it will not be a problem.

Comment: No, it won't be noticeably slower. You can adjust the number of PIOPS according to your performance and budget. More PIOPS == faster + more expensive, fewer PIOPS == slower, cheaper

Comment: What is the default storage of EC2 instance? How GB is it? What is the file system of EC2? What must be the file system of EBS? Do they need to use the same file system? So that EC2 can read from EBS and write to EBS (EC2 instances will write different files at different directories.)

Answer (score 3):

You can pre-build an [Amazon Machine Image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html) (AMI) that includes these libraries and then launch N instances from that AMI. That will be the fastest way to get the same libraries onto all of your EC2 instances.

You could also measure the time taken to download them all from S3 into EC2 as that, if reasonably quick, would reduce the overhead of having to maintain your AMI (as security patches become available, etc.)

To bootstrap files from S3 onto an EC2 instance, you can do this one-time at launch using a [userdata script](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html), or pull them on demand.

For more sophisticated options, you could look at the Code* services, for example CodeDeploy, [multi-attached EBS volumes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-volumes-multi.html) (these are read-only) or even [EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/) (which is probably overkill in your case).

Comment: If I upload the library files to S3 bucket, do I need to download them to each EC2 instance for computations? I thought that each EC2 instance can make of use files in S3 bucket directly.

Comment: By 'library files' I assumed they were executable (like DLLs or SO files) and hence they would be needed locally. If they're data files, then absolutely you can just leave them in S3 snd access them remotely. Note that you won't have the typical file-level access to them however, at least not out of the box. You'd have to use S3 APIs to access them. If you need to be able to access then as if they were local to the EC2 instance then you could look at S3 FUSE solutions and mount the S3 bucket. I'm not a huge fan of this type of solution except in small, well-controlled, read-only scenarios.

Comment: These library files are data files, .bed files. I need each EC2 instance to reach them to read the file from the given full path to the file. So if S3 FUSE solutions are complex, I must avoid S3 usage.

Comment: FYI downloading 1000x10MB files from S3 into EC2 in the same region takes under a minute, typically. Not sure what your requirements are here.